JavaCard CAP Conversion Fails with "Invalid AID" Error Using JCOP SDK
I've tried about 100 different renditions of the converter command, different AIDs, using only the applet AID, removing the "1.0". It always results in "Invalid AID".
I was able to successfully create a cap just once using a different java version with XML but the cap file was almost 400kB and it was clearly created incorrectly.
I'm using and prefer Java 7.
Here is the command:
./converter.sh \
  -classdir /Users/X/Desktop/javacard/emvcoapplet/bin \
  -d /Users/X/Desktop/javacard/emvcoapplet/cap \
  -exportpath /Users/X/Desktop/javacard/jc320v24.0_kit/lib/api_classic-3.0.5.jar \
  -applet A000000333010101 emvcoapplet.EMVCoApplet \
  emvcoapplet 1.0 A0000003330102

The resulting error message:
Error Message:error: invalid AID A000000333010101.
Usage for compact CAP files:
    converter <options> package_name package_aid major_version.minor_version
    OR
    converter -config <filename>
    ...

Applet Snippet:
package emvcoapplet;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.*;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;
import javacardx.crypto.*;

public class EMVCoApplet extends Applet {

    private static final byte[] AID = { (byte) 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x33, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new EMVCoApplet().register(AID, (short) 0, (byte) AID.length);
    }

    private EMVCoApplet() {
        cipherAESCBC = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_CBC_NOPAD, false);
        initializePreStoredTLVStructure();
        initializeKeys();
        initializeOwnerPin();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte cla = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA];
        byte ins = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

        try {
            if (selectingApplet()) {
                return;
            }

            if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != CLA_EMV_APPLET) {
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }....

Project Structure:
emvcoapplet
├── bin
│   └── emvcoapplet
│       ├── EMVCoApplet$TLV.class
│       └── EMVCoApplet.class
├── build.xml
├── cap
├── lib
└── src
    └── emvcoapplet
        └── EMVCoApplet.java

Java Card kit:
jc320v24.0_kit
├── bin
│   ├── capdump.bat
│   ├── capdump.sh
│   ├── capgen.bat
│   ├── capgen.sh
│   ├── converter.bat
│   ├── converter.sh
│   ├── exp2text.bat
│   ├── exp2text.sh
│   ├── verifycap.bat
│   ├── verifycap.sh
│   ├── verifyexp.bat
│   ├── verifyexp.sh
│   └── verifyrev.sh
├── legal
│   └── THIRDPARTYREADME.txt
└── lib
    ├── api_classic-3.0.4.jar
    ├── api_classic-3.0.5.jar
    ├── api_classic-3.1.0.jar
    ├── api_classic-3.2.0.jar
    ├── api_classic_annotations-3.0.4.jar
    ├── api_classic_annotations-3.0.5.jar
    ├── api_classic_annotations-3.1.0.jar
    ├── api_classic_annotations-3.2.0.jar
    ├── asm-9.4.jar
    ├── commons-cli-1.6.0.jar
    ├── commons-logging-1.3.0.jar
    ├── jctasks_tools.jar
    ├── json.jar
    ├── logging.properties
    └── tools.jar


Have you also set the module AID? Right click on the package in JCOP, hit properties and then you can fill that one in. Best to fill in all 3 AID's, the other two are set for your Applet-derived class of course. You need to create a release version if your cap file is too large, also a setting in properties. What ever you do, always clean up the project, as JCOP often fails to do this if the properties are changed. Restart Eclipse if need be. And whatever you do, disable f***ing McAfee for your build folder.

ive actually been handing everything through terminal on a mac fairly successfully but im no pro with javacard specifically. the command i provided does list the module/package aid if im correct. also the insanely large cap file created was with a higher java version. im not sure my applet will be compatible with my jcop card if i update to a higher java. just assuming thats a factor....if you dont believe higher java will cause compatibility issues im open to try anything at this point.

You are saying that you are using JCOP, but you seem to use the Oracle converter (which is why I was wrong-footed). There is a lot in the question that can be the cause of confusion to be honest.

youre correct, thats what i was recommended initially and ive been running with that. any recommendations would be amazing. it seems nxp jcop tools are only obtained by contacting them which is understandable but i hear they rarely respond so i dont think im going to waste my time with that. any other ways to convert my applet to work with a jcop180k or jcop40k would help so much.

There are good reasons for them not reacting to any request. Before the easiest way was to buy an eval kit, but I'm not sure if that's still the case.

From the error message:
major_version.minor_version package_aid major_version.minor_version

From your command:
emvcoapplet 1.0 A0000003330102

The version number and AID have been swapped, obviously if the version number is parsed as an AID then it won't be accepted as one.

I guess we've all been there... sorry for the previous comment, I was staring at it as hard as anyone here.

lol that could very well be the case. hopefully it is, ill need to get back at it today. i guess when youre staring at a project for months its usually the most obvious things that haul progress for weeks

it was simply the aid. the bytes were too long and the command required "0xA0:0x00:0x00" format and a few changes. worked perfect and after clearing up a few applet errors i was able to create the cap....now for testing screams internally. do you know anything about jcardsim?

@keepaerie First of all, could you maybe self answer? That way others that have the same problem can find the right command line structure! I did have a look at the jcardsim project some time ago and sparingly used it. I've considered it for testing, but please be aware of possible differences with JC, such as the absence of the transaction system (unless they fixed that), API's timing etc. Back in the days I had some ideas of improving it mainly to perform initial testing on the business logic - the final product definitely should be tested using a real card though.
